# [WARN][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport][PC name]received plaintext http traffic on an https channel,closing connection Netty4HttpChannel

Tags: elasticsearch

I have downloaded the Elastic search zip from here,
https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch
and run the elasticsearch.bat file from the bin folder and in the CMD I'm getting something like this when I hit localhost:9200 in the browser
[image: CMD output]

and not getting any response in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

as the error suggests, you are using http when you should be using https